# Specifying id for jQuery event

Tags: jquery, popup, jquery-events

I have this little function to do something after a pop-up is loaded:

```
jQuery(window).on('jet-popup/show-event/before-show', function () {
                        console.log("popup open");
});
```

This is working but unfortunately this goes for every pop-up on my site and I want it only if the pop-up with a specific id is showing. I tried this but this is not working at all. I'm getting no errors but it doesn't work either.

```
jQuery(window).on('jet-popup/show-event/before-show','#popup_id', function () {
                        console.log("popup open");
});
```

Comment: Can you provide details for `jet-popup`?   `jet-popup/show-event/before-show`?  and `#popup_id`?  See [mcve].   What triggers the popup?   Did you inspect `this` inside your handler?

Comment: jet-popup/show-event/before-show is the event every pop-up fires if i trigger it in any way. Every popup has it's own id. Currently my function is fired every time, any popup is triggered. But I actually want it just to be fired, if the popup with id "#popup_id" is triggered.

Comment: There might be data associated with the event that could tell you for which modal the event was triggered. You could try `jQuery(window).on('jet-popup/show-event/before-show', function (event) { console.log(event); });` and see if there is anything useful.